# CXF wsimport XJB Binding for Multiple Schemas add XmlRootElement annotation

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf

I am using CXF to create contract first webservices classes.
I have a wsdl which has a load of xsds imported.
These xsds are all in one package in my Java project.

I have created a XJB file which does the job I want but takes up too much code to maintain if I am going to have a lot of xsds which I am expecting. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

XJB:

```
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="wsdl-xsd/contacts_input.xsd#REQUESTType"
    node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='REQUESTType']">
        <annox:annotate target="class">
            <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement"
                name="REQUESTType" />
        </annox:annotate>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="wsdl-xsd/contacts_output.xsd#RESPONSEType"
    node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='RESPONSEType']">
        <annox:annotate target="class">
            <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement"
                name="RESPONSEType" />
        </annox:annotate>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

WSDL:

```
<!-- Contact Services -->
        <xsd:import namespace="http://contacts_request.global_test.ws.test.com" schemaLocation="contacts_input.xsd"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://contacts_response.global_test.ws.test.com" schemaLocation="contacts_output.xsd"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to fix this issue by using the simple minded binding which gave my complex elements the @XMLROOTELEMENT annotation. I decided to make an anonymous root element having the complex type of REQUEST/RESPONSE type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
jaxb:version="2.0" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
<jaxb:globalBindings optionalProperty="wrapper">
    <xjc:simple />
</jaxb:globalBindings>
```